# Liferay autofields: retrieving indexes in the controller

Tags: liferay

I´m trying to use auto-fields in the configuration of my portlet, but I´m getting desperate with an issue: in the action, I can retrieve the datafields but not the fields indexes in the controller. When I get it from the action request, it´s an empty String :(

Here´s the code from the jsp corresponding to the fields:

```
<div id="fyhespecials">
        <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">
            <div class="row-fields">
                <aui:input id='fecha0' name="fecha0" label="Fecha" />
                <aui:input id='horario0' name="horario0" label="Horario" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here´s the script:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
AUI().ready('liferay-auto-fields', function(A) {
    new Liferay.AutoFields(
    {
    contentBox: '#fyhespecials', 
    fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace/>indexes'
    }
    ).render();
});
</aui:script>
```

And in the controller, I just can´t get the indexes from the actionRequest, but I can get the fields "fecha(index)" and "horario(index)". However, I need the indexes to get the fields properly, so I´m stuck right now. Maybe is saved within the actionRequest, but named in a different way.

Would appreciate some help :)

Thanks in advance,

Luis.

PS: just for providing additional info (in case it was useful), the portlet is running in a Liferay 6.0

EDIT: As requested, here is the code in the controller that tries to catch de String of indexes. Note that, in the syso made below, this String comes empty, while the fields (fecha0, fecha1...) are shown correctly:

```
public class ListadoMuseoConfigurationActionImpl extends
        DefaultConfigurationAction {

    public void processAction(PortletConfig portletConfig,
            ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
            throws Exception {

            String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,
                    "portletResource");

            PortletPreferences preferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil
                    .getPortletSetup(actionRequest, portletResource);

            //...

            String indicesString= actionRequest.getParameter("indexes");

            String fechaEspecial = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "fecha0");
            String fechaEspecial1 = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "fecha1");
            //...

            System.out.println("=============Indices autofields======="+indicesString);
            System.out.println("=============fechaEspecial======="+fechaEspecial);
            System.out.println("=============fechaEspecial1======="+fechaEspecial1);
```

Hope this helps to get to a solution.

Comment: Would you please add controller code snippet here?

Comment: Sure, but I can´t do it right now . I will add it on Monday :)

Comment: Just added it. Forgot to clear up that I´ve been trying a lot of variants of this code, f.e. change the name of the String of indexes, get the actionReuqest parameter with ParamUtil... but failed to sort this out.

Comment: It's probably a typo in the question, but when you instantiate the component, you're specifying a field named `indexes`, but in your sample code you're using `indices` instead.

Comment: You´re right, adolfopa, it´s a typo in the question due to some adaptation I made from the code I have to be easier to understand; I just corrected it. Thanks for the note, mate :)

Comment: Have you inspected the request parameters (actionRequest.getParameterMap())? That may show something (e.g. if you forgot the TLD declaration, you'll see a literal '<portlet:namespace/>indexes' parameter). Also, just in case, make sure the content box you're specifying lies inside the HTML form.

Comment: I´ve done a complete scan of what´s coming within the actionRequest, and there´s a parameter called indexes, but it comes empty. The other parameters (fecha0, horario0, fecha1, horario1 and so on) are registered correctly inside the actionRequest. 

Also checked that the contentbox (#fyhespecials) is inside the form.